# canvas повёрнутое изображение не масштабируется, не работает ctx.restore();

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas

загружаю картинку, поворачиваю, а когда начинаю увеличивать или уменьшать она возвращается в состояние до поворота.
координаты хочу вернуть в точку 0,0 потому что дальше будут дорисовываться другие элементы

```js
var img;
var tttRotate = 0;
var tttScale = 1;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  img = new Image();
  var f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
    url = window.zURL || window.URL,
    src = url.createObjectURL(f);
  img.src = src;

  img.onload = function() {

    ctx.scale((canvas.width / img.width), (canvas.width / img.width));

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  };
};
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

function Move(a) {
  switch (a) {
    case 'plus':
      if (tttScale < 1) {
        tttScale = 1;
      }
      tttScale = tttScale + 0.05;
      break;
    case 'mines':
      if (tttScale > 1) {
        tttScale = 1;
      }
      tttScale = tttScale - 0.05;
      break;
    default:
      tttScale = 1;
  }

  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  ctx.scale(tttScale, tttScale);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}

function Rot() {

  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.save();
  tttRotate += 90 / 57.2958;
  var x = img.width / 2;
  var y = img.width / 2;
  var width = img.width;
  var height = img.height;
  // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(tttRotate);
  ctx.drawImage(img, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
  ctx.rotate(-tttRotate);
  ctx.translate(-x, -y);
  ctx.restore();
}

function doCanvas() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF8F00';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body onload="doCanvas()">
  <input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Move('mines')" target="_self" id="a_33ff_4">Minus</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Move('plus')">Plus</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Rot()">rot</a>

  </br>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" ;></canvas>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы много раз переобъявляете img и ctx, соответственно, для каждой функции - это разные объекты. Код ниже - работает, но я советую вынести повторяющиеся куски в отдельную функцию, например imgProceed(img, ctx, scale, rotate), ну или как вам удобнее.

```js
var img;
var tttRotate = 0;
var tttScale = 1;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x;
var y;
var width;
var height;

function draw() {
  ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  img = new Image();
  var f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
    url = window.zURL || window.URL,
    src = url.createObjectURL(f);
  img.src = src;

  img.onload = function() {

    ctx.scale((canvas.width / img.width), (canvas.width / img.width));

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  };
};
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

function Move(a) {
  switch (a) {
    case 'plus':
      if (tttScale > 2) {
        tttScale = 1;
      }
      tttScale = tttScale + 0.05;
      break;
    case 'mines':
      if (tttScale < 0) {
        tttScale = 1;
      }
      tttScale = tttScale - 0.05;
      break;
    default:
      tttScale = 1;
  }
  ctx.save();  
  x = img.width / 2;
  y = img.width / 2;
  width = img.width;
  height = img.height;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  ctx.scale(tttScale, tttScale);
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(tttRotate);
  ctx.drawImage(img, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
  ctx.restore();
}

function Rot() {

  ctx.save();
  tttRotate += 30 / 57.2958;
  x = img.width / 2;
  y = img.width / 2;
  width = img.width;
  height = img.height;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.scale(tttScale, tttScale);
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(tttRotate);
  ctx.drawImage(img, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
  ctx.restore();
}

function doCanvas() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF8F00';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body onload="doCanvas()">
  <input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Move('mines')" target="_self" id="a_33ff_4">Minus</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Move('plus')">Plus</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Rot()">rot</a>

  </br>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" ;></canvas>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```